# fakeAsync() or done()?

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

When you write an Angular test using Jest and you have to test asynchronous operations do you prefer to use

```
  it('', fakeAsync(() => {
    // test goes here 
  }));
```

or something like

```
  it('', (done) => {
    // test goes here 
    done()
  });
```

I tried both but `done()` seems to give me more explanatory error messages. Also, I am not sure if they are mutually exclusive

Answer (score -1):

You dont need done or fakeAsync. Jest supports native async support like the following example

```js
it('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
  const data = await fetchData();
  expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
});
```

As you see, we just declare a async function and jest will cover the rest